# Eclipse (C++), is there a way to forbid editing files with specific ending?

Tags: eclipse, pycharm, development-environment

Context:
We are working with a custom file ending. Those files get parsed to .cpp and .hpp before compilation. 
I always find myself editing the .cpp files that are overwritten later on.

Is there a way to stop or warn me when doing this?

In PyCharm, there is something similar, where it automatically warns me when I'm trying to modify project-external files. 
Alternatively, if PyCharm or another editor can do this, it would also be helpful.

Comment: There is a 'locked' attribute on the Resource page of the Properties for a file that prevents changes

Comment: Thanks, that's already somewhat useful. But everytime the file is removed and re-created, this property is reset, unfortunately.

Comment: (And for me there was no 'locked' attribute, but I could set and remove write permissions there.)

Comment: Looking at the code, Locked is only present if the file system supports it (I am on macOS which does support it). The program creating the files would have to set the file permissions.